# How to Test in case Unittest By pass file excel to Import API

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i'm will test code by TestCase of django.test and APIClient of  resrt_framework.test with excel file, where do i can test thus import api

test_import_file.py

```py
import xlrd

from django.test import TestCase

from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from account.models import Account

from account.tests import create_super_user

from instructor.models import Instructor

from utils.excel import get_value

class TestClassImport(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.account = create_super_user()
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.account)
        self.url = 'static/example/example_class_import.xlsx'
        self.file = open('static/example/example_class_import.xlsx', 'rb')
        self.wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=self.file.read())
        self.sh = self.wb.sheet_by_index(0)


    def test_real_import(self):
        file = open(self.url, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore')
        url = '/api/dashboard/content-migration/import/instructor/'
        self.response = self.client.post(url, file)
        self.failUnlessEqual(self.response.status_code, 201)
```

I hope it will "test_real_import (class.unittest.test_import_file.TestInstructorImport) ... ok"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add every thing to task of celery and call it by unit test of django

'python'

```
from your_app import your_project_task

class TestInstructorImport(TestCase):
fixtures = ['instructor/fixtures/instructor.json', 'account/fixtures/account.json']

def setUp(self):
    self.account = create_super_user()
    self.file_path = '/yourpath/name.xlsx'

def test_task_import(self):
    response = task_execute.delay(self.file_path)
    self.assertEqual(response.result, 'Done.')
```

code "self.assertEqual(response.result, 'Done.')"
in task just

```
return('Done.')
```

when your code done without any error.